# how to get unique record from table in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having two tables called `abc` and `xyz`. The table `xyz` contains column id and `xyz` contains `abc_id`.

I want to find record present in first table but not present in second table. How can I do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch records from abc table which not in xyz table;

```
SELECT abc_id FROM abc 
WHERE abc_id NOT IN (SELECT id from xyz)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id from xyz 
where id not in ( Select abc_id from abc)
```

See more details about `NOT IN()` comparison function [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in)

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN as @m.hasan answer or use [EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

```
> Select id from xyz  where not exists ( Select abc_id from abc where
> abc_id = xyz.id)
```